# How to pass variable in AJAX to node js file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ajax

I tried coding in AJAX where I need to pass data `newval` to data post.

```
function turnplug2On(){

    var newval=this.getAttribute("data-id");
    newval=newval+"On"
        $(document).ready(function() {   
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:8124/',
                    timeout: 2000,          
                    data: '{"data":"plug2On"}',


                });
            });
        }
```

Instead of passing hardcoded value in data , I wanted to pass `newval` variable.. can you please help explain how to do this.

```
    http.createServer (req, res) => {
    //console.log('request received');
    //util.log(util.inspect(req));
    console.log(req,res);

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        //console.log(chunk);
        //req.on(function (chunk) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
        console.log(obj.data);

        switch (obj.data) {
}
}   

    });
   // res.end('_testcb(\'{"message": "Plug1!"}\')');
    //res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');

}).listen(8124);
```

Thank you.

Comment: is plug2On your hardcoded data ??

Comment: change `"plug2On"` to `newVal`

Comment: why is there a   $(document).ready(function()  inside the function ??

Comment: plug2on hardcoded for testing purpose. This function is called by some other html file. document.ready I have added just for the page to get loaded while clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
function turnplug2On(){

var newval=this.getAttribute("data-id");
newval=newval+"On"
```

then do your thing...and pass it to the ajax function...

```
function turnplug2On(newval){ 
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:8124/',
                    timeout: 2000,          
                    data: '{data:'+newval+'}',


                });
            });
 }
```

btw what is the $(document).ready doing inside the function ???

Comment: I tried this.. I have a req code in server as req.on('data', function (chunk) {..} when I tried this, the response i am getting is undefined:1

Comment: are you using nodejs.. then in that case...can you post the server side code too.. in your question...

Comment: http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //console.log('request received');
 //util.log(util.inspect(req));
 console.log(req,res);
 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
 req.on('data', function (chunk) {
  //console.log(chunk);
  //req.on(function (chunk) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
  console.log(obj.data);

  switch (obj.data) {.......} 
  
    });
   // res.end('_testcb(\'{"message": "Plug1!"}\')');
 //res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');

}).listen(8124);

Comment: event I am not able to edit your question...you have to clear your edit queues...

Comment: Edited the quest. Is it fine now ?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the way to do this. 
In Ajax, 
I have used 
data: JSON.stringify({data:newval}), 
So that the value will be JSON stringified for the nodejs to read the data